# Finding Flowdirection in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, localization, c#-4.0

Is there any way to find the flow direction of current culture in Silverlight 4.0. I know its possible in full .net with `CultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft`, but since Silverlight has a cut down form of `CLR` and the internal implementation of `IsRightToLeft` in .Net uses `COM`, this property is not available in Silverlight version of `CLR`.

Any suggestions of setting an extension method?

I know to provide checking the culture name and set the direction as right to left only for say hebrew, arabic etc. Is this the only way???

Thanks